# Identifying inserts, updates, deletes, and conflicts between a parent and child version in ArcSDE with ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, versioning

I'm looking for a way to identify records that have changed between the present and the last time a version was reconciled.  It would also be great to be able to identify conflicting records.  Ideally I would be able to read in the attributes of the records that have changed or are conflicting.

I suspect that this is possible doing some sort of comparison with the delta tables, though I have very little experience with versioned features and ArcSDE itself.  I've looked around and haven't found any information on how to actually read or access those delta tables.

Is there a way to achieve this within Arcpy?

Answer (score 1):

If your versions are representing database replication then, sure, it's easy. See [Export to Delta](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000011000000) which is depreciated, and [Export data change message](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Export_Data_Change_Message/00170000001m000000/).

If you are not using a replica then it's not so easy. There is [database tracking](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000068000000) which may help. The adds and deletes for each feature class are stored in geodatabase tables but are not exposed to the outside world from the ESRI interface. You can access them using the database directly but not from ESRI (arcpy) objects. If you are editing directly to a version (not default) then you can possibly compare your edited version to the default version by supplying appropriate version information on a tool like [feature compare.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_Compare/001700000004000000/)